# How to hide “Area” name in URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My problem is that when i am not in my "Admin" area the link shows up as "**/blog**" however when i am in my "Admin" area the link turns to "**/admin/blog**".

I have an "Admin" area and i have specified a layout page in a viewstart file in the "Admin" area View section. Markup below:

```
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

The markup of my link looks like this (this link is in my _Layout.cshtml view):

```
 <a asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link"> Blog </a>
```

My routes look like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

And my controller in my "Admin" area looks like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Area("Admin")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
```

I have tried adding asp-area="" so my a tag would look like :

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link"> Blog </a>
```

But this just leaves the href empty when looking at it through developer tools.

So my question is how can i remove the area name from the url?

I feel like it is something really easy but i cannot figure it out. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682170/asp-net-mvc-areas-how-to-hide-area-name-in-url) thread but it is not in .net core so the solution does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be linked to your route definitions. Try combining the routes into a single UseMvc call and also placing the more specific area route first.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Following that, you could switch your  tag to use `asp-route="default"` instead of using `asp-controller="..."` and `asp-action="..."`.

Comment: wow i cannot believe i didnt try this. I had to use your solution combined with adding asp-area="" to the a tag and it worked. Thanks a thousand!!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked. For what it is worth, I would recommend using the `asp-route="default"` named route approach, because you're effectively trying to target that specific `default` route. If you do that, it looks like you'll need to also specify `asp-route-controller="..."` and `asp-route-action="..."` as well.

Comment: @MattBrooks not works. If I used `asp-route="default"`, it always load home url only.